# How Do I export an SVG without it getting an <image> element and not a <path>

Tags: svg, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I keep exporting a PSD element with a clear background as an SVG and I continue to get

```
    <svg 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="0.972in" height="0.861in">
<image  x="0px" y="0px" width="70px" height="62px"  xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEYAAAA+CAMAAAChgZ0aAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAACfFBMVEUnKzT///8nKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzQnKzT///8hMYv/AAAA0nRSTlMAAA1LkMbm9/zu1qllHguTyej4++zTpiAfhuDvoDIVfNzyQQjt+RJh4asmLsjj3zuo/uvpYK5mMxkHDyVO9Fokz/UJEylTlN2ITyEQa+L9lidfOrmlGNfVPwyEgRaOA3rwN7O3FFFSp4VwtULnSaHNDlSbBMvaApVMZJ2wvqwBbRrzUEMGWQqZmBzHReXQaRuy5N6epMF3gzQrwC0w8b2aez2MSK9iPijZ0pKxztE5EcTYn8JE9lgjcyyNzGyKRzWH+r9vo4+ticNngtsxxR2qOLbCHslsAAAAAWJLR0QB/wIt3gAAAAd0SU1FB+IKERAGN8eMmYsAAAQVSURBVFjDpZdnQxNBEIYnBBBUSkgEARURSBBsoEJQrCCCINgQYwV7byhYEUWDWLBhwYIFe++99172F7kzOUKSu0u52w9X5t082b0t8y6AQ/HT+gcEdmAsKLhjp84h4FpCtWHhugjG9IYukZ2jhKCGikOtrtExzKHEduvuBOkR19NRju/USwqTEJfIXEpSmLGdYkp2lVnvFBEmtU+bGNy3H3aMSsf+gmwcIETS0mOSB+qFF8MgF4zW1pT4wRmZ5tCsIUOzw2wdHDac5BEj6W3UYFNqj4TROblj8sbaQPlOmIIIguSPa+9EYdF4jBWb+HMK/UhfMsFhNCZ2IU6eA2bSKIxMznUeGPMUjAYVQOlUfCib5ixbphNnhh0zkzowa7ZohOdgvLxiLt7mzRfJC+JRWNiGWYRvi0GiLKEvgpeloyXkZchZbrZhVmC1lSBZooUxWbVaUl6D2lrCVK7jj+ulq0HVZNskyJWWoRo/fSpitFhvg0w1iIpFeaOcXNiXq5sQs5k/bAHZYuLy1hpZeRsOQqkGarfzhx3yGKibvnGnvFqo4z83aWAXv423guJSb2vtbuyccgp92pgG2MNvE1VgzHzu6PfCPr5qM1VgavbzdjTCMP6lD6jAaA5yTDQUM3bITw1mE8fUA78c3qkGk0dLiV/6ZanB4Ho4AkmM6YxqME0c4w8GxiKGqsEc5ZhjUMavK1RgLLg410Bvfj2uAnMijbHEZtrgwmuUY3CjPZkFp4L4ZD6tmFKFqWeOBqrC+b1aMaYOt79mvm0V8YczIUoxuMm24O5nxI3nrEIKpYMdlBnOYbvOK6JYcbqsqyTMEMx2ZaFKMBewMa1CusN9lJUo6VIx2hN7Dr+InEs+U8bhV00PsWMOBGKOvewjxY8s0S4HY9KKrdNd8YkyGxMcq3aySccwdLWrLxjc9fgycDZtmGfYNbP3lOv0x6Uu3q/yBoZv1npL8cfqumaRE7W0oHDLy1WRRz7jNoh98Z27KN2b4AWk8j5ZRTLGInttfIBisufcZ91KZq4OJDFQSP0yPPRAmU/VEgVHKcaAhczio8duKU/IIwdWgCwGssjDpj11Q6kg29rzGbjBCAPJnstuzgXlqL9on6jSGNp9+LKVSesvg8iI54AnDJiSsGaA5MJ4Rf+x0jFZy2HgtQHrHn4jEiy2Y8xbp6AsBk5fpWPZApdwCM3Pd43gJQZq39Oh44NTMJMOd4la8BoD1o/U/E9V7aFs8tnru4MPGIDFxPm8uu29iIbogdjeucdAxjv8XR/hgPuFqJES/tkDBlrT7QNmiZQYIi8xkEqHuthsaPhK5+BvoAgDZhow/Xc6VRpkvJRnDFib7GfuHz9BMQYgX6D8+g1qMFBEA/ZH3oB7h4G/98P/DXKj2zD/AZ/Mbsp7NMuGAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
</svg>
```

I would like to export this as a `<path>` element instead of `<image>`

this is the PNG of what that SVG is:

[image]

I have converted already tried to image trace this on illustrator but the path gets sloppy.

Thanks,
Zlerp

Comment: What is the element you are trying to export? Is it a raster image or a vector shape? If you are trying to export a rasterised image, it'll create a contained `<image>` as PhotoShop can't convert that to path data. Illustrator is much better suited to this task. Start by tracing the image, then manually tidy up the result by moving/deleting points.

Comment: Photoshop is the wrong tool for making SVGs. Draw your shape in Illustrator instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry but Photoshop just doesn't do SVGs like that. SVG is a vector format and the only things in photoshop that are vectors are paths and selections and neither of those have things like line thickness and color so they'd be invisible as an image.

That's what Illustrator is for. Or for a free option, there's [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/).